# Inaccuracy addSubview in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

There was a big problem that I can not solve for a couple of days.
I have a UIViewController with UICollectionView in which there will be 3 cells with different content. Here is my class:

```
class PostView: AppViewAddMenu, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
var homeController: FeedController?
var contentArray = [PostContentModel]()
var postInfo: PostModel?
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    return cv
}()

override func setupViewController() {
    collectionView.register(PostViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-60-[v0]|", views: collectionView)

    fetchPost(id: postInfo?.id)
}

func fetchPost(id: Int?){
    guard let ID = id else {
        print("ID faild")
        return
    }
    let url: String = "https://FTP.ru/wp-json/mobileApi/v1/post/\(ID)"
    ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchContent(url: url, completion: { (Posts: [PostContentModel]) in
        self.contentArray = Posts
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
    cell.contentArray = contentArray
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
}
}
```

The idea of the first cell is to take json from a site that looks like this: `[switch, content]`. From the switch value in UICollectionViewCell, different functions are called, which add an element in UICollectionViewCell via `addSubview ()`. Here's the code:

```
class PostViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = .white
    anchor = self.topAnchor
}

var anchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?
var contentArray: [PostContentModel]?{
    didSet{
        for number in contentArray! {
            if(number.switcher == 1) {
                anchor = addTextContent(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
            if(number.switcher == 2){
                anchor = addImageContent(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
            if(number.switcher == 3){
                anchor = addCaptionFirst(content: number.content!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
            if(number.switcher == 4){
                anchor = addButtonLink(content: number.content!, link: number.link!, bottomAnchor: anchor!)
            }
        }
    }
}

func addTextContent(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor{

    let shortContentPost: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = content
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        return label
    }()

    addSubview(shortContentPost)
    shortContentPost.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    return shortContentPost.bottomAnchor
}

func addImageContent(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    let image: CustomImageView = {
        let image = CustomImageView()
        image.image = UIImage(named: content)
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.clipsToBounds = true

        return image
    }()


    let imageURL = "https://brodude.ru/wp-content/uploads/" + content.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
    image.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: imageURL)

    addSubview(image)
    image.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 250)

    return image.bottomAnchor
}

func addCaptionFirst(content: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    let Caption: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = content
        lb.numberOfLines = 0
        lb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        return lb
    }()

    addSubview(Caption)
    Caption.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 30, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    return Caption.bottomAnchor
}

func addButtonLink(content: String, link: String, bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor) -> NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    let button: LinkButton = {
        let bt = LinkButton()
        bt.LinkString = link
        bt.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        bt.setTitle(content, for: UIControlState.normal)
        bt.sizeToFit()
        bt.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        bt.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        bt.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.07, green: 0.32, blue: 0.89, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState.normal)
        bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(linkOut), for: .touchUpInside)
        return bt
    }()
    addSubview(button)
    button.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    return button.bottomAnchor
}
```

The algorithm works satisfactorily, but the problem begins when the cell is updated. When scrolling, with `collectionView.reloadData ()`. New subview layered on the past, the text becomes fatter and clogged device memory. The process continues indefinitely until it gives an error.

Example of a problem:[image: View], [image: First indicators],

[image: Indicators after 15 scrolls up]

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, instead of:

```
addSubview(shortContentPost)
```

use:

```
contentView.addSubview(shortContentPost)
```

Do this for all the subviews that you add. `contentView` is supposed to hold your content.

Implement this `prepareForReuse` in your cell:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    let subviews = contentView.subviews
    for subview in subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This will clean your cell's content before reusing the cell.

Although I would **STRONGLY** recommend **NOT** to add/remove those subviews dynamically, because then you lose much of the reuse mechanism. I would add all the views (labels/imageViews) to the cell by default, and then use their  `isHidden` property to hide/unhide them based on the content (e.g., if an image should be show, set the `isHidden` to `true` on all the others). This would be performance-wise better for reusing, because then the UI objects will not have to be recreated everytime a cell is reused, you would just reconfigure the content of the labels/imageViews.

Comment: A cell is a text that has many different elements. The problem is that it is not known how many elements will be used and in what order they will go. Therefore, the dynamic filling of the post, the only thing I came up with. Your method is being executed, but the problem does not resolve.

Comment: @Евгений check the beginning of the updated answer.. I assumed that you add your content to `contentView`.. add ALL your ui components to `contentView`, and then my `prepareForReuse` will work